# Chrome Download Attribute not working to replace the original name

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've experienced some unexpected behavior of Chrome since the newest version:
While in Firefox this Code is working Perfectly fine:

```html
<a 
  id="playlist"
  class="button"
  download="Name.xspf" 
  href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,PD94ANDSOON" 
  style="display: inline;">
    Download Me
</a>
```

It isn't working in Chrome (Simply downloading a file named "Download"), but has worked pretty fine before. What do I have to change that it is working again?

Comment: This also happens when you are opening your website without a server (like a localhost), installing and using Ritiwick Dey's Live Server extension in VS code solves the problem, you can also use any other server like apache or xampp, but it would be easier and faster to install VS Code's Live Server extension.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After some research I have finally found your problem.

`<a>`'s download attribute:

> If the HTTP header `Content-Disposition`: is present and gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority over this attribute.

> If this attribute is present and `Content-Disposition`: is set to inline, Firefox gives priority to `Content-Disposition`, like for the filename case, while Chrome gives priority to the download attribute.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

HTTP-Header [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

Comment: My Server doesn't seem to send "Content-Disposition" and as described by you Firefox wouldn't donwload the File correctly, but my problem is reversed: Chrome isn't accepting the download attr, while Firefox does. Even if i just create a simple HTML file with only this as its content (and opened as a file-url) it won't work in Chrome but in Firefox. It also worked before I updated Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114 m)

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome for me as well... I surfed some sites with a "Try it" page, but neither their examples didn't work, nor some JSFIDDLE I tried to make. The only one which worked was [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2) on W3Schools.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Chrome as of version 35:                           https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182

Comment: Thanks for sharing, hopefully they'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: I'm getting chrome ignoring the "download" attribute... such a pita really

Comment: @MrMesees If I remember correctly, browsers no longer honor the download attribute, unless the href points to a resource that is on the same origin. Also see the answer below

Comment: This doesn't actually provide a solution

Comment: @RyanWalker The solution is to use the Content-Disposition HTTP Header.

Comment: That works if you have control over the server, but isn't a solution for the Front-End.  I still can't figure out how to do it in html when the server doesn't have the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: if I store files in aws s3, and want to download files using presigned URL - this solution wont works for me, right? I am familiar only with front-end part - that is why asking

Answer (score 73):

Reading the comments, I had the same issue as @buffer-overflow and found this in [the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182#c64):

> I'm guessing that the web page and the download are on different origins. **We no longer honor the download attribute suggested filename for cross origin requests.** Clicking on the link still initiates a download. But the the filename is only derived from factors solely dependent on the server (e.g. Content-Disposition header in the response and the URL).

So no chance I could make it work ... :(

Comment: There is nothing about that restriction in the W3C recommendation of the HTML5 and HTML 5.1, but you can find at the Mozilla reference. "This attribute only works for same-origin URLs." - from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: I have the same problem with chrome version 57 despite no `Content-Disposition` header is present.
The only solution I found was to make the server add the `Content-Disposition` header and specify the filename there.

Comment: i am seeing totally different behavior... it's not even *trying* to download, instead it's acting as if the download attribute wasn't there, and is replacing the page with the new image!

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem with wordpress, the problem is that wordpress generates the full path of the file, and in the a tag you have to remove the full domain name and add a relative path

Example, instead of:

```
<a href="http://mywordpresssite.com/wp-content/uploads/file.mp4" download="file.mp4" >
```

You have to do this:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/file.mp4" download="file.mp4">
```

This will make it work

Comment: This is not related with the original question, but has solved my life :)

Comment: Same here. It seems that perhaps Chrome assumes it is from a different domain if the whole domain is specified, even if that isn't true.

Answer (score 4):

This is the current behaviour in Chrome as of **16 Aug, 2021**

If you are calling an api like this:
http://localhost:9000/api/v1/service/email/attachment/dummy.pdf

Chrome will try to parse the last value of the path param and ignore any value passed to *`attachment`* attribute of `a` link if `Content-Disposition` is not set or is set to *`inline`* from the server, in which case the pdf file will have the name *dummy.pdf*

If `Content-Disposition` is set to *`attachment`*, then chrome will save the file with the *`filename`* value from Content-Disposition header.

That is if the server were to respond like this:

```
res.setHeader(
  "Content-disposition",
  "attachment; filename=" + "server-dummy.pdf"
);
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```

The file would be saved as *server-dummy.pdf* regardless of the presence of download attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple solution regarding this issue. You just need to put your html file into a server like Apache using xampp control and so on. Because the download attribute is properly working through a server.

```
<a download href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,PD94ANDSOON">Download Me</a>
```

Comment: This unfortunately is limited to 1MB of data, at least in Chrome 73

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the `file-saver` NPM Package to implement or force download.

1. Install `file-saver` package

```bash
# install via npm
npm i file-saver

# or install via yarn
yarn add file-saver
```

2. import `saveAs` function from `file-saver`

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
```

3. use `saveAs` function

```js
saveAs('https://httpbin.org/image', 'image.jpg')
```

**References**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver#saving-urls // direct url to **Saving URLs**
- https://www.javascripting.com/view/filesaver-js

Comment: I tried most solutions on Youtube and Stackoverflow, and this is the only solution that works. It is also very easy to apply.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having problems with this when the address of the file is different from this one, you could try to:

1. Locally create a `Blob` from downloading locally the original file.
2. Creating a `URL` object based on the local `Blob`.

It would look like this:

```js
const outsideRes = await fetch(outsideUrl);

const blob = await outsideRes.blob();
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = url;
link.download = "marketing-payout-report.csv";
link.click();
```

Comment: This seems to have just broken in the past couple days. Perhaps a Chrome security update? I can't find any info or workarounds. Downloaded filenames are random UUID hex with no extension - https://imgur.com/a/EK5vCL9

Comment: @JeffWard I am also having problems starting recently. Odd differences too. Using the same browser (different tabs) I view pages on two different instances of the same application (but different versions). The download divs look the same, but on the older app version when I click the download I get it failing with a Resume button and "Check internet connection". Found a suggestion to delete the download tag, which seems to have worked, but no idea why. I think Chrome broke something, but not sure why version specific. (It's the old version that broke!) Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Sinc - like you, I found a workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77284332/1026023), but no clues as to the reason it changed. 

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the files via a web server or your local filesystem - Does the browser's URL bar start with http:// or file:///?
I just ran some tests in Chrome, and while it will download the file, it doesn't respect the value of the download attribute when you're using the local file.

If you start hosting it on a web server, this will start working. If you're just doing this for yourself on your computer, check out WAMP for Windows or MAMP for macOS to get started with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work without a server. `download` attribute will do the work only when using a server (local/remote) like tomcat/xampp/wampserver...

```
<a href="videos/sample.mp4" download>Download Video</a>
<a href="images/sample.jpg" download>Download Image</a>
```

Not just only for videos or images.

Answer (score -3):

This can be resolved by adding `target="_blank"` attribute to the `href`.

Like this:

```html
Save sprites.svg as 
<a target="_blank" download="somefilename.svg"
href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg"
>somefilename.svg</a>
```

Comment: Can confirm, it works with Chrome 72 when the response header doesn't specify a filename.

Comment: Does not work, please do try first before suggesting it to someone.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome 76, FF 68 and Edge

Answer (score -4):

The file has to be in some zipped format!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend you to check this guide on how to give a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Sometimes, although you might think you just gave the correct solution, you should try to explain why is this the case to provide more insight for the community.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -17):

Go To Chrome Click on “Settings” and you'll see a new page pop up in your Chrome browser window. Scroll down to Advanced Settings, find the Downloads group, and clear your Auto Open options. Next time you download an item, it will be saved instead of opened automatically.

Comment: Perfect for someone who doesn’t care where his downloads go and how they are named – the opposite of the solution we are seeking.