# Custom file name of file to download in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, download

I am trying to download a file with custom name from any url.

I am trying this on my code

```
downloadAttachment(attachment) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = attachment.url; //URL FOR DOWNLOADING
    a.download = 'CustomName.png';
    a.click();
}
```

and from view it is `<button (click)="downloadAttachment(attachment)"></button>`

It is downloading the file but filename is still picked up from the url.

> How to add custom name to the file?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How to add custom name to the file?

Comment: i mentioned it 'CustomName.png'

Comment: I will be providing a meaning full name later for now, i just need to make it possible to have a custom name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: is present and gives a
>   different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority
>   over this attribute.

Check the response headers.

[Chrome Download Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working)

So you will have to change your back end where the file is stored, if possible.

EDIT:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

> This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

Edit2:

```
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<File> {
    return this.http
        .get(imageUrl, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
        .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
}
```

Now you have a file in your memory, and you can save it however you will.

Comment: the file is stored in s3

Comment: Check the response headers in your network when downloading the file and find Content-Discposition attribute. If it's there, you can't really acomplish what you're asking.

Comment: response headers don't have a Content-disposition, I will look into aws s3 to how to add cusotm headers and then i will add 'Content-Disposition: inline' and check.

Comment: seems like the best option for me now is to save the file with the desiered name on s3, best to support all the browsers

Comment: I guess. You could also download the file as Base64 and save it as you wish. Check the edit again.

Answer (score 5):

Download file with **http.get:**

```
    let queryApi = someApi
    this.http.get(queryApi, { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe(respone => {

            // file-type
            let fileName = 'custom-file-name.fileExt';             

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(respone.body);
            link.download = fileName;
            link.click();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way

```
<a [href]=URLoftheFile download="FilenameWithExtension">DownloadFile</a>
```

But does not work with cross origins