# HTML5 Download Attribute Does Not Download File

Tags: html

I have familly mkv files and would like to make when user click on "MyFamilly"  tag to download myfamilly.mkv file...in chrome it open that file and i want it not to open just download file...here is my try:

```
<a href="ftp://myserverip/myfamilly.mkv" download>MyFamilly</a>
```

So how to force chrome to automatically download file not to open it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Download Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working)

Comment: This is because of the latest chrome update. Chrome now blocks cross-origin downloads. [Ref : https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4969697975992320 ]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`<a href="ftp://myserverip/myfamilly.mkv" download="download">MyFamilly</a>`

Comment: Thanks...but it opens mkv file in chrome...it does not download it...what version of chrome are you using? A upgraded chrome to lastest version yesterday and on new chrome version it opens it not download...so i im thinking that new chrome version have changed somthing in their code...my chrome version is: 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)