# A hyperlink download attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html

so i have this problem with hyperlink attribute download. basically i have link that download a certain file. however it doesnt work..

```
<a href="somelink/somefile.txt" download="" class="external">download file</a>
```

With this format, it will download the file but it will give me an failed file says 'no file'.

On the other hand if i have link that has a complete uri format:

```
<a href="http://wwww.somesite.com/somelink/somefile.txt" download="" class="external">download file</a>
```

It redirects me to the page and it will just show the file. The weird
thing is when I tried it on mozilla and brave browser. it works. but
in safari, and my default is google chrome. its not working..

Am I missing something? maybe in my header? really appreciate if you can help.. thanks!

**EDITED**

also, i've read this stuff about content disposition, so how do i know that my webpage set as inline for that matter. [image]

Comment: It seems like you have tow problem. one is the relative path could not found file. the other is the browser support about link download attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Download Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working)

Comment: i am looking for solution. the answer didnt give solution just found out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873370/6545866, a content disposition but see my edited question, i asked if how do you know if you enabled it or if you set to inline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it turns out, my problem is conflicted by same origin urls. Apprently, I am rquesting from different hosts/site, for further explanation see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

If you look at here https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_a.asp

Scroll down to attributes, and you will see that the DOWNLOAD attribute is only supported by HTML5, which, as it seems, your friend's version of Safari does not support. I recommend updating the program.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the download link, then click Save As..., then download it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be caused js intercepting navigation and redirecting. If so, you may be able to work around it by adding a `target` attribute.

```html
<a href="file.txt" download target="_self">download file.txt</a>
```