# Image not downloading on click, rather than opening up URL of image

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting a problem to download the image on click, It is opening up the URL of the image rather than download. I have tried other StackOverflow Answers as well but nothing really solves my problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="d1" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1816/0091/files/Artboard_3_1.png?11554335258293208175" download="aa.jpg">
    <img  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1816/0091/files/Artboard_3_1.png?11554335258293208175" width="104" height="142">     <span>Click to Download</span>
  </a>
  <script>
    document.querySelector(".d1").setAttribute("download", "filename.jpg");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you have an error in your console because you are trying to reference an element before it is rendered to the page..... someone can find the dupe.

Comment: And there's also a typo in `filename.jpg"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)

Comment: @A.Meshu Thanks for the another refrence of this topic But it still different from that one As, My code is running but the browser not downloading the image instead it opens up the URL

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for your answer I have changed the code. As Recommended by  but still image is not downloading in the browser. It opens up in the same tab.

Comment: @A.Meshu Did you read my comment below my answer? `download` doesn't work in all browsers and even in those that it does work in, it must be tested over HTTP/HTTPS. My answer does do what you asked about in that is correctly sets the `download` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @A.Meshu for your reply again. I have tested on HTTP as well its still not working. It would be great if you can have a look at the link http://down.goslash.co.nz/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: @epascarello I am looking at it. Give me few minutes

Answer (score 0):

1. Your class is `d1`, but in `.getElementsByClassName()` you
   search for `dl`.
2. Your code attempts to find that element before the element has
   been parsed into the document, so you need to move the script to the
   bottom of the web page so that by the time that code executes, the
   element will have been parsed.
3. You are missing an opening quote in front of `filename.jpg`
4. `.getElementsByClassName()` is the wrong choice here as it returns a
   "live" node list (which is only useful in certain use cases and
   hurts performance in all others) and because, you aren't interested
   in a node list, you're trying to find just one element. Use
   `.querySelector()` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="d1" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1816/0091/files/Artboard_3_1.png?11554335258293208175" download="aa.jpg">
    <img  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1816/0091/files/Artboard_3_1.png?11554335258293208175" width="104" height="142">     <span>Click to Download</span>
  </a>
  <script>
    document.querySelector(".d1").setAttribute("download", "filename.jpg");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott Marcus for your help but it still the same problem I am getting browser not downloading the image instead it open up the URL of Image.

Comment: @VarunKumar If you run my code snippet and then right-click on the link and choose Inspect, you will see that the download attribute it now set up correctly, **so the code now sets the attribute correctly**. Note that `download` only works over HTTP/HTTPS (not when accessing the page directly from the file system) and `download` [isn't supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility) as well.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I have tried running on HTTP and tried to click on google chrome/ Mozilla Firefox but it's still not working. Please have a look http://down.goslash.co.nz/

Comment: @VarunKumar This could simply be that Shopify doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott Marcus I have changed the src of the image and its still the same problem. Can you please have a look again at down.goslash.co.nz

Comment: @VarunKumar Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working

Comment: I am looking at it. Give me few minutes

Comment: Thanks @Scott Marcus, I have read that implemented that but its still not working