# Automatically download file after load page php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to implement a script on an html template where after loading the template, the file download starts automatically.
My files in question are txt, csv and xlsx.

After 2 seconds, as per setTimeout, the script is activated but it does not download the file, but opens a new page as the content of it.

Another question I wanted to ask was whether it is possible to put the absolute path of the file as the folder containing them is nested at a higher level than `$ _SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`.

```
$file = '/var/www/.........../file.txt';
    echo "<script>
                \$(function() {
                    \$('a[data-auto-download]').each(function(){
                    var \$this = \$(this);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.location.href = \$this.attr('href');
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <a data-auto-download href=\"".$file."\">here</a>";
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working) might help you to understand, how to force browsers to download files instead of displaying them.

Comment: Maybe only ```window.location.href```can be enough for this