# How to make image downloadable if it is not on same server but i.e. in AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, imagedownload

Image is in AWS S3:

```js
<a
  data-lightbox-anima="fade-top"
  className={`btn`}
  download={`${organizationShortId}-${programId}`}
  href={`https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${organizationShortId}-${programId}`}
>
  Insta
</a>
```

How can I make it downloadable with button / link and not opening in browser?

Checked this, found no solution: [Chrome Download Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working)

---

In S3 I do not control Content-Disposition header.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download

Comment: yes, I did set `download` field, it does not help

Comment: Yes but according to documentation you don't have to pass the download attribute link url as value, that is specified in href

Comment: Ah, "Download Restrictions
The download attribute only works for same-originl URLs. So if the href is not the same origin as the site, it won't work. In other words, you can only download files that belongs to that website. This attribute follows the same rules outline in the same-origin policy."  https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/38-html-download-attribute/

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do? Image is not "malicious document", but we store images not in Next.js's public folder but in AWS  S3?

Comment: you could create a "downloader" route, something like `yoursite.com/download?resource`, fetch the external file server-side and then use `header` to pass the file as download. Check this answers, server-side code is in PHP (and it's about pdf files) but the concept is the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802607/5334486

Comment: I use a `middleware` to do it, but get stuck with an other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581788/how-to-get-noticed-image-was-downloaded-to-be-able-to-start-a-new-task