# Downloading blob: URL -> filename is random UUID

Tags: javascript, html

**Goal:** I'm trying to download some binary data `Blob` to the user's computer as a specific filename (more importantly, with a specific extension.) `my-filename.ext`

**Setup:** I'm using `URL.createObjectURL` to create a `blob:` URL, injecting it into a `<a href="blob:..." download="my-filename.ext">` link.

**Problem:** The resulting downloaded filename is *sometimes* (see clue below) a random UUID with no extension, instead of the filename specified via the `download` attribute. See my [Recent Downloads screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYFz1.png).

**Crazy clue:** On most websites, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com pasting this code in the dev console works, and it downloads with the correct filename. But on a couple websites, including https://saga.org it fails, downloading a random filename.

**Code snippet:** Create a **Download** button to download some random data as `my-filename.ext` - paste this into the dev console and click the Download button.

```js
function create_blob_url() {
  var hexdata = "a8c7390b9102c748609de9f817ab"; // arbitrary data

  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(hexdata.match(/.{2}/g)
                                .map(e => parseInt(e, 16)));
  var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return url;
}

function do_download() {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = create_blob_url();
  console.log('Loading URI: '+link.href);
  link.download = "my-filename.ext";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}

var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'Download';
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener('click', do_download);
btn.style = "position:fixed;z-index:2147483647;top:0;left:0";
```

Comment: On which browser are you experiencing this issue? I can't repro on Chrome 118 for macOS. Also, what happens when you deactivate all your browser extensions?

Comment: @Kaiido Here's a screen recording repro with all the details: 
https://youtu.be/RD6KXfTFtZ4

Comment: Interesting. Could you try to update your browser? Once again, I can't repro on 118 on macOS. If it still happens in the latest version, then open an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/wizard

Comment: FYI, downloaded Chrome 118.0.5993.117 just now, same behavior. Chrome 118 on Windows, same behavior. I don't have a Mac to verify your result.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically a duplicate of [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749) - the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/1026023) suggests using the [FileSaver.js library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/tree/master), which is a good idea. It doesn't have this problem.

Digging into the FileSaver source code to find out why, I found a snippet linked to [issue 465](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/465) indicating the `link.click()` doesn't work in all browsers. Indeed, replacing that with `link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))` fixes this problem.

As to why this occurs on some sites and not others - it's still a mystery!

Comment: I've had similar problems with downloads, but it's even weirder. My app, which has been out for quite a while, suddenly can't download backup data tar files. I can repro on our v3 but not our v4. Same HTML code in both, same browser instance. Colleague found that if you hard reload you can do one download, have to reload again for a second. Suggestion somewhere said to try removing the download attribute from the anchor tag, which seems to work, but has some side effects. I have to look at the solutions to see if anything works reliably. v3 is almost EOL, but I need the downloads for upgrades.

Comment: The other thing is that when it fails the download tab in Chrome shows me a Resume button and says "Check internet connection", while the connection is fine, since I can switch tabs to another instance running v4 and download without problems. Can't find any meaningful documentation about the error except it claims to be having network issues of one of about 4-5 possible types.